# Any extra steps needed to publish an Parse.com Android app to Google Play Store for push notifications to work?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I just published my Android app to Play Store about an hour or two ago. Push notifications have always been working while in development stage. When I saw the app was available for download, I uninstalled the debug version and installed the Play store version on the same device. I then tried to send a push message via Parse.com and couldn't receive any messages. I have another phone with the debug version installed keeps receiving push messages. So I wonder if any extra steps or changes in configurations are need to perform for apps ready for publish.

POSSIBLE CAUSE - Since the same phone was used as debugging and production, Parse.com probably gets confused which version is installed on the phone.

SOLUTION - Uninstall app on phone and delete installs in Parse.com. Then re-install app on phone via Play Store.

Comment: please read the documentation! - it is all about signing the app  - the debug version is using deifferent key then release version

Comment: @Selvin thank you so much for quick response! sorry for asking the obvious (cause I am very new), which key is that? i know for google maps, different sha1 keys needed to be registered at google developer console. In fact, i have been wondering if the same is needed for push notifications. But i have no clues. You mentioned documentation, do you mean that of Parse.com? Cause I have gone through all the guides and tutorials on push notifications and couldn't find anything on this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Selvin it turns out the problem got nothing to do with whatever keys you are refusing to share with me.Someone at Parse.com's google groups forum had experienced the same and found the solution is removing the install object associated with the testing device. Working now without making any changes. Guess it's kind of a bug thing.

Comment: @Selvin I would be most grateful if you could kindly consider remove your vote down on my question. It seems clear to me now you are not responding to my question tagged with parse.com. And somehow you had wasted hours of my time on something that is completely irrelevant to my question and refusing to elaborate on what kind of keys you deem the cause of my problem associated with Parse.com.

Comment: @Selvin thanks for removing your downvote

Answer (score 0):

Parse Push requires Google Play Services' Google Cloud Messaging API(s).  In addition to all the conventional code, permissions etc.  For Android Studio, as a minimum for Parse Push:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0' //for parse push (selective)
}
```

in the app's build.gradle... Alternatively, you may use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' //for parse push (contains entire play-services)
```

which contains ALL Google Play APIs but leaves a larger app footprint.

You can read more about it [HERE](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview)